# segue to 3 tab in UITabcontroller is not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue, viewcontroller

I created a prepare segue function when user click "ok" on UIAlret it will go to 3rd tab controller in BaseTabBarViewController but I have a problem with prepare function is always going to the 1st tab

```
   func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "segueToUsersTab"){
            if let tabVC = segue.destination as? BaseTabBarViewController{
                tabVC.selectedIndex = 2
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using old prepare for segue method. The fix  change it to override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {